# HoloEverywhere Spinner OnClickListener() Error

Tags: java, android, spinner, android-holo-everywhere

I define my spinner as follows:

```
import org.holoeverywhere.widget.Spinner;

private static org.holoeverywhere.widget.Spinner sectionSpinner;

sectionSpinner = (org.holoeverywhere.widget.Spinner)findViewById(R.id.sectionSpinner);

 <org.holoeverywhere.widget.Spinner
        android:id="@+id/sectionSpinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/circleSeek"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="center" />
```

This line, however, throws an error:

```
sectionSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new SectionListener());
```

The error is `The method setOnItemSelectedListener(AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener) in the type AdapterView<SpinnerAdapter> is not applicable for the arguments (MainActivity.SectionListener)`

Here is the SectionListener class:

```
public class SectionListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, 
            int pos, long id) {
        if (userSelected) {
            resetAction();
            setTimeText(sectionTimes[pos], sectionTimes[pos]);
            currentSection = pos + 1;
            setSectionText(currentSection);
            currentStartTime = sectionTimes[pos];
            currentTime = currentStartTime;
            setSeekBarProgress(currentTime, currentStartTime);
        }
        else {
            userSelected = true;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // Not needed
    }
}
```

This error does not occur when I use the regular Android spinner. Anyone know what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try defining `SectionListener` class as

```
public class SectionListener implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener
```

**EDIT**

You could also try passing an anonymous instance of the listener.-

```
sectionSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, android.view.View v, int pos, long id) {
        if (userSelected) {
            resetAction();
            setTimeText(sectionTimes[pos], sectionTimes[pos]);
            currentSection = pos + 1;
            setSectionText(currentSection);
            currentStartTime = sectionTimes[pos];
            currentTime = currentStartTime;
            setSeekBarProgress(currentTime, currentStartTime);
        } else {
            userSelected = true;
        }
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    }
});
```

**EDIT 2**

It seems that *HoloEverywhere* lib includes its own `AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener`, double check you're listener extends

```
org.holoeverywhere.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener
```

Comment: Same result unfortunately.

Comment: Ok, any chance you defined `SectionListener` in its own java file and have duplicated id also inside `MainActivity` class?

Comment: I have another Java file (SectionsActivity) that has a (different) class with the same name. Could that cause an issue?

Comment: According to the error, you're trying to pass `MainActivity.SectionListener`, in other words, a `SectionListener` class defined inside `MainActivity`, which I'm guessing does not implement `OnItemSelectedListener`

Comment: The SectionListener defined in MainActivity is the one I have shown in my question.

Comment: Mmh not sure what's happening, just edited my answer with an alternative approach using an anonymous instance, no need to create a specific class for your listener in this case.

Comment: Now it is saying: The method setOnItemSelectedListener(AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener) in the type AdapterView<SpinnerAdapter> is not applicable for the arguments (new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){})

Comment: Sorry, my bad, just realized about HoloEveryEveryWhere. It seems the library includes its own `OnItemSelectedListener` (org.holoeverywhere.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener). That's the listener you need to extend.